# Intent recognition using only one intent

Tags: chatbot, wit.ai, rasa-nlu, named-entity-recognition

I am currently trying to extract from texts some sentences/groups of words that mean "there was an anomaly on this satellite at this date regarding this equipment" using **rasa_nlu**.

I have thought to intent detection because I had already used wit.ai and recast.ai for chatbots and I thought that trying to extract this kind of thing from a text could be like talking to a bot with the text and waiting for him to detect the "anomaly" intent.

However, this means that I have only one intent in my model and rasa doesn't seem to work thus for intent detection (it does good named-entity recognition but 0 intent detection).

**Is there another way to extract what I want to extract using rasa or any other tool ?**

Thank you in advance

Antoine

Comment: That's a classification problem

Comment: @Yasen I agree but there are obstacles to text classification in my context: -all my data are in PDF files and it is not always possible to extract sentences -some sentences deal with the causes of an anomaly or the fact that there has been no anomaly on a subsystem of a satellite and will be wrongly classified because of their vocabulary.